# How to extract characters from a string with optional string afterwards using Regex?

Tags: regex

I am in the process of learning Regex and have been stuck on this case. I have a url that can be in two states `EXAMPLE 1`:

```
spotify.com/track/1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA?si=Nf5w1q9MTKu3zG_CJ83RWA
```

OR `EXAMPLE 2`:

```
spotify.com/track/1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA
```

I need to extract the `1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA` ID

So far I am using this: `(?<=track\/)(.*)(?=\?)?` which works well for Example 2 but it includes the `?si=Nf5w1q9MTKu3zG_CJ83RWA` when matching with Example 1.

BUT if I remove the `?` at the end of the expression then it works for Example 1 but not Example 2! Doesn't that mean that last group `(?=\?)` is optional and should match?

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

I searched a handful of "Questions that may already have your answer" suggestions from SO, and didn't find this case, so I hope asking this is okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capturing group in your regular expression is trying to match anything (`.`) as much as possible due to the greediness of the quantifier (`*`).

When you use:

- `(?<=track\/)(.*)(?=\?)`

only `1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA` from the first example is captured, as there is no question mark in your second example.

When using:

- `(?<=track\/)(.*)(?=\??)`

You are effectively making the positive lookahead optional, so the capturing group will try to match as much as possible (including the question mark), so that `1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA?si=Nf5w1q9MTKu3zG_CJ83RWA` and `1HYcYZCOpaLjg51qUg8ilA` are matched, which is not the desired output.

Rather than matching anything, it is perhaps more appropriate for you to match alphanumerical characters `\w` only.

- `(?<=track\/)(\w*)(?=\??)`

Alternatively, if you are expecting other characters , let's say a hyphen `-` or a underscore `_`, you may use a character class.

- `(?<=track\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?=\??)`

Or you might want to capture everything *except* a question mark `?` with a negated character class.

- `(?<=track\/)([^?]*)(?=\??)`

As pointed out by gaganso, a look-behind is not necessary in this situation (or indeed the lookahead), however it is indeed a good idea to start playing around with them. The look-around assertions do not actually consume the characters in the string. As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/5VTWZG/1/), the full match for both matches only consists of what is captured by the capture group. You may find more information [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 track\/(\w+)
```

Please see [here](https://regex101.com/r/dLCvLF/1).

Since track is part of both the strings, and the ID is formed from alphanumeric characters, the above regex which matches the string "track/" and captures the alphanumeric characters after that string, should provide the required ID.

Comment: @gagnso wow thanks I was making this MUCH more complex than I needed

Comment: I guess just for clarity, we should not include the `track/` in the result so it should be `(?<=track\/)(\w+)`

Comment: This is indeed a solution however it doesn't really help OP understand what the problem was with his initial expression

Comment: @pkpkpk thank you very much for the detailed explanation, both helped explain a few ways to approach this for the future

Comment: @pkpkpk, thanks for the explanation. Jordan, using look-behind would provide you the answer but isn't necessary here. Look-behind is usually helpful when you want to have zero-length assertions. Please read https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Regex : `(\w+(?=\?))|(\w+&)`
See the demo for the regex, https://regexr.com/3s4gv .
This will first try to search for word which has '?' just after it and if thats unsuccessful it will fetch the last word.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the answer (your regex) itself. Imagine what would happen if the link gets broken in the future.